# Tight connection of \vbox es

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, tex-core, boxes

I don't understand why TeX put a thin whitespace between my two vertical boxes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\vbox to 1cm {\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\vbox to 1cm {\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\end{document}
```

I would like this to show no whitespace between the black squares.

Comment: `\lineskip` glue. Just add `\nointerlineskip` between the boxes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `\vbox` has for reference point the one corresponding to the last item in it, in this case the lower left corner of the rule. With `\vbox to 1cm` you force a height of 1cm (you probably have something else than a rule).

The second `\vbox` will be placed below the first one, but TeX always does its computations related to the interline skip. Since 1cm is way more than `\baselineskip`, under normal circumstances, TeX will insert `\lineskip` glue between the items.

No `\parskip` glue will be inserted, though, as a paragraph is never started.

Answer: inhibit the insertion of interline glue with

```
\nointerlineskip
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\vbox to 1cm {\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\nointerlineskip
\vbox to 1cm {\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\end{document}
```

(blank lines can be used, because no paragraph will be started).

More information about `\nointerlineskip` can be found in TeX by Topic or, of course, the TeXbook.